# Batch update in db2 on a table through Databricks

Tags: python, pyspark, db2, databricks

Below is the code....

```
from datetime import datetime, date
def update_chk_table(ENV, notebook_name, df):
    # Create a connection object using a jdbc-url, + sql uname & pass
    connection = spark._jvm.java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password)
    connection.setAutoCommit(False)
    statement = connection.prepareStatement(
        """update CPYDB01.CHK 
           SET CHK_UPD_USR = ? and CHK_MSG_LN = ? 
           WHERE CHK_NBR = ? AND BANK_ACCT_NBR  = ? AND BANK_ABA_NBR = ? AND CHK_ISS_DT = ?"""
        )
    try:
        # loop through the dataframe and add batch updates
        for row in filter_fpdb_reisstyp_df.collect():
  
        statement.setString(1, chk_upd_usr_value)
        statement.setString(2, chk_msg_ln_value)
        statement.setBigDecimal(3, spark._jvm.java.math.BigDecimal(str(row['CHK_NBR']))) 
        statement.setBigDecimal(4, spark._jvm.java.math.BigDecimal(str(row['BANK_ACCT_NBR']))) 
        statement.setBigDecimal(5, spark._jvm.java.math.BigDecimal(str(row['BANK_ABA_NBR'])))
        statement.setDate(6, chk_iss_dt_str) #Where condition CHK_ISS_DT
        statement.addBatch()
```

When executed I am facing issue. so attached is the screenshot for issue reference:

[image: When executed I am facing issue. so attached is the screenshot for issue reference]

I tried batch update through Databricks on a table in db2. My expectation is the table to get updated on two columns for all the records in the dataframe that i am passing as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Check out how an [update](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-update) is done in SQL.

In the Set clause the columns need to separated with a comma and not combined with "and"